# Extending the solution of an elliptic operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-operators

Suppose I have a second order elliptic operator $L$, with smooth coefficients, defined on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the open unit disc $D$. Then $L$ is uniformly elliptic on $D$, by compactness argument. Now consider the Dirichlet problem,
\begin{align*}
Lu &= f,\\
u|_{\partial D} &= 0
\end{align*}
where $f\in C^\infty_c(D)$ is compactly supported and smooth. This admits unique weak solution $u$, which is smooth by Elliptic regularity.

I would like to know, under what condition on $L$ can I extend $u$ *smoothly*, by setting it $0$ outside $D$.

Any help regarding this appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

(1) As discussed in the comments, simply extending the solution by zero on a larger disc and then appealing to uniqueness and regularity doesn't work. The obvious extension is a priori only continuous and not even a weak solution (on the larger disc).

(2) It is suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292633/regularity-up-to-the-boundary) to apply Schauder existence theory repeatedly to obtain smooth solution up to boundary, but I am not sure if I understand the argument. Also does it help to extend beyond the boundary?

Comment: My guess would be that you need $f$ to have support in a set $U$ which is smaller than the unit disk. Then you can invoke the same uniqueness argument on the smaller set $U$, argue that the solutions on $D$ and $U$ have to agree, hence the solution on $U$ can be smoothly extended by zero. I think if $f$ cannot be smoothly extended by zero then the solution can't be either.

Comment: @quarague Since $f$ is compactly supported in the open disc, it is definitely smoothly extendable. But I am not sure how to show that the (unique) solution on $D$ and the (unique) solution on $U\subset D$ has to agree in $U$.

Comment: The solution on $U$ solves the system of equations on $D$, so by uniqueness it has to be the same solution.

Comment: @quarague But to show that the solution, say $v$, on $U$ solves the system on $D$, we need to have an extension, no? If we set $v$ to be $0$ beyond $U$, we only get a *continuous* function on $D$. This extension is not a weak solution either.

Comment: You are right, this is more messy than I thought. I still feel this should work out but it is not a trivial argument.

Comment: @MaoWao Could you please give me a reference for this fact?

Comment: The Schauder estimates are used to give regularity up to the boundary, but they're always $H^k$ estimates whereas here you need $H^k_0$. I'll have to think on this further, but if one takes $f$ to be a nearly like a point source about the origin then $u$ will behave like the Green's function of $L$ near the boundary of $D$, so you'll need a condition on the coefficients $L$ so that the Green's function behaves like an element of $H_0^k$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I'm not very familiar with Green function. When you say, $f$ to be _nearly_ like a point, is there any way to quantify this? I can take $\textrm{supp} f$ to be really small and concentrated about $0$ by multiplying it by a bump function.

Comment: This can fail even in the simplest case when $L=-\Delta$. Let $u$ be such that $u(x)=\log|x|$ for $|x|>1/2$ and $u$ is smooth on $D$. Then $u|_{\partial D}=0$, $\Delta u$ is smooth and $\Delta u(x)=0$ for $|x|>1/2$. Thus $\Delta u\in C_c^\infty(D)$. But of course, the extension of $u$ by $0$ is not smooth on $\mathbb{R}^2$. This makes me very skeptical that it holds for any $L$.

Comment: @ChesterX By Green's function I mean the fundamental solution for the elliptic operator $L$. And yes, you can construct $f$ to be point-source-like by taking it to be a smooth bump function supported on a small domain, and then scale it so that it integrates to $1$.